# Scale intervals on x and y axes in my line-chart plotter JS app not getting displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, html5-canvas

I am creating a vanilla JS application which uses **CANVAS API** to plot line charts for any given co-ordinate data in JSON format.
I have almost completed the app but **I want to display the scale intervals on 'x' and 'y' axes**. But the text is not getting displayed correctly. It is **getting repainted over and over** at the same place.
I want it to look like this-
[scale interval demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T2bM.png)

Here is my JS code-

```js
function drawAxes(data, margin) {
  //the margin parameter contains the distance of x and y axes from the edge of the canvas

  for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    //axisDigit holds the scale intervals like 10, 20, 30 etc.
    let axisDigit = 10;

    ctx.fillText(
      `${axisDigit}`,
      margin - 20,
      canvas.height - (margin + axisDigit)
    );

    axisDigit += 10;
    console.log(axisDigit);
  }
}
```

Now for some reason the loop isn't working correctly and axisDigit is stuck at 20. Console logging shows that the axisDigit, i.e, 20, is getting logged during every iteration. Please comment if the question is not clear since this is like the first or second question I am asking on stackoverflow.

I am also linking the github repo of this project. You can also read through the JS code. Its quite small - just 90 lines - to be precise. I am unable to link the working jsfiddle demo because it is not working in jsfiddle. Please see how it is turning out in my github repo.[graph-plotter in github](https://github.com/mehulambastha/Graph-Plotter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your version you set `axisDigit` to 10 at the top of the loop with `let axisDigit = 10;`, then you add 10 at the bottom of the loop with `axisDigit += 10;` and log it which should log `20`. Next time through the loop, it will begin again and set `axisDigit` back to 10, add 10 again, which will set it back to 20, and log `20` again, and repeat.

You probably intended the value of `axisDigit` to persist between loop iterations, which means you'll have to declare it outside the loop (before the `for` statement)

So you probably want to change:

```
 for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    //axisDigit holds the scale intervals like 10, 20, 30 etc.
    let axisDigit = 10;
```

to

```
 //axisDigit holds the scale intervals like 10, 20, 30 etc.
 let axisDigit = 10;

 for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
```

And leave the rest of the body of the loop the same.

Final version looking like this:

```
function drawAxes(data, margin) {
  //the margin parameter contains the distance of x and y axes from the edge of the canvas

  //axisDigit holds the scale intervals like 10, 20, 30 etc.
  let axisDigit = 10;

  for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    ctx.fillText(
      `${axisDigit}`,
      margin - 20,
      canvas.height - (margin + axisDigit)
    );

    axisDigit += 10;
    console.log(axisDigit);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Wyck. It was certainly very foolish of me to reset the axisDigit on every iteration. Thank you loads